# Is there a way to not generate a service-worker?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-cli

With the polymer CLI https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli
I can't run something like `polymer build --add-service-worker false --entrypoint ./elements.html` right? Is there a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [polymer-cli README](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli#build), the `build` command is highly opinionated and it generate the Service Worker as default behavior.

Comment: Jep, had to write my own build